# Можно ли внедрить веб приложение на JS в окно PyQT интерфейса?

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyqt, интерфейс

Например, есть карта с определенным функционалом, которая отображается в браузере, и соответственно написана средствами JS. Можно ли каким нибудь образом интегрировать содержимое браузера в интерфейс приложения на PyQT? Если да, то какие средства нужны для достижения этой цели?

Comment: Вам наверное нужно добавить стёк технологий которые используются, или это просто скрипт?

Comment: Вам карту показывает браузер, но сервис на чём это всё основанно ведь гораздо сложнее или нет? В Qt есть свой движок браузер.

Comment: @Александр на самом деле нет, там все достаточно просто. Используется openStreetMap, и некоторая логика (добавление сетки, возможность ставить метки на карте, отображать значки объектов, которые перемещаются и тд)

Comment: Ну так откройте этот url средствами QWebengineview.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @Александр, понял, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @S.Nick, разве здесь у всех только одни проблемы возникают?) Не может быть просто вопроса, который направлен на уточнение используемых технологий?) Я же не код прошу писать, все таки)

Comment: Effex, sorry, да, можете. Такой ответ вас устроит?

Comment: @S.Nick, ну давайте представим, что вы решили что-то разработать, и банально не знаете, при помощи каких средств можете достигнуть своей цели. Вы задаете вопрос, посредством которого намереваетесь выяснить, что это в принципе реализуемо и хотите уточнить что вам для этого понадобится. Затем получаете ответ: "да, можете". Вас бы устроил такой ответ?)

Comment: Вы спросили 'можно ли', вам ответили да можно, в чём проблема мусье?

Comment: Effex, мне для того чтобы вам что-то рекомендовать, надо видеть (как минимум), что вы хотите внедрить в  PyQt и что вы хотите в результате этого получить.  The End.

Comment: @S.Nick, да уже все, мусье Александр подсказал все необходимое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос звучит так:

> Можно ли каким нибудь образом интегрировать содержимое браузера в интерфейс приложения на PyQT?

То ответ - Да можно.

А если нужен скрипт, то сначала покажите ваши достижения в этом вопросе.

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен скрипт, мне просто нужна подсказка, какие средства использовать в целом, чтобы я мог предоставить "минимальный воспроизводимый пример"))

Comment: Средство QWebEngineView

Comment: Спасибо. Это стандартное средство, или его необходимо откуда то подгружать?

Comment: Нужно установить через пакетный менеджер pip, кстати если вам помог ответ то можете принять его.

Comment: pip install PyQtWebEngine

Comment: Ну вот и все, что мне нужно было)

Comment: Стрелочку вверх ещё нужно. :-)

Comment: Ой, извините, запамятовал, вы определенно заслужили :) Жаль нет возможности несколько раз нажать :( Побольше бы таких людей, которые дают быстрые и лаконичные ответы...

Comment: А мой вопрос не заслужил стрелочку вверх? :(